# How to add count search results and display the number of search results?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I worked the answer out so no need now thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$countquery='SELECT count(*) FROM ((' . $query. ') as alias)'
```

Comment: I inserted this in to the bottom of my code and I echoed $counterquery but all I got back was the query actually written out

Comment: you have to execute the query like you have for the previous query something like this $countquery= $conn->prepare($countquery)->execute();

Comment: so something like this:$countquery="SELECT count(*) FROM ((' .$query. ') as alias)";
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($countquery);
      $stmt->execute();
     
      echo $countquery['count'];

Comment: you can do echo $countquery['alias'];

Comment: it just echoes the letter S which I think is the start of the query

Answer (score 0):

You can look through the docs for the `mysqli` class:

```
echo $stmt->num_rows;
```